# I want split div with diagonal line

Tags: html, css

I would like to have this [Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3LVt.jpg) using html5 and css3. And divide the div with diagonal lines, how can I do this?

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a Question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: We don't write up code here, so update your question properly if you want to keep it open and get proper answers

Answer (score 0):

- A way can be using a background image, with the diagonal line as a background image.
- Another way is using html `<hr>`, and use the css 3 rule `rotate` to achieve that
  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp